# Facebook app requires repeated sign-in

Tags: facebook, password

Recently, the Facebook app on my Droid 1 (Android 2.2.2) started prompting me to sign-in throughout the day. I get a pop up that says:

Facebook Sign-in
Please re-enter your Facebook password

It shows my username and asks for my password.

It seems that if I don't use the phone for a few hours, when I pick it up, this sign-in is waiting for me.

Any ideas why? or what changed?

---

Update - not sure, but http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?p=13331773 says

> It seems like the mobile app doesn't
>   play nice with HTTPS (secure browsing)
>   if you have it enabled on the Facebook
>   website. After disabling HTTPS on the
>   full Facebook website under Account
>   Settings, I was able to log in and
>   stay logged in without an issue.

I don't want to give up secure browsing, but perhaps there was a bug in a recent udpate to the app?

Comment: do you have any apps that are killing processes and clearing app data to free up space?

Comment: Are you using the very latest Facebook app from the Market? Have you tried clearing the cache and/or data?

Comment: I can't check from here, but could there be a security setting at facebook.com related to remote/mobile access that you recently changed?

Comment: I have no apps running that automatically kill processes. (i have Advanced Task Killer free installed, but AutoKill is disabled.  Yes, Facebook is up to date from the Market.

Comment: I don't see any facebook settings on the web site that are related to mobile apps. the Account Settings-Mobile is mostly about SMS messages and cell phone numbers, not iPhone or Andoid apps.

Comment: Hmmm...I have my Facebook settings to "always use HTTPS" and I'm not seeing this behavior. Let me look in my settings again.

Comment: Have you tried a complete uninstall and reinstall?

Comment: Is the Facebook app installed on the SD card?

Comment: It might have been. I haven't had this problem in months. They've made so many updates since then and I even have a new phone. Was SD card install a problem?

Answer (score 1):

I had issues with the last Facebook update, the one that came out the past 2 weeks.  I uninstalled it and reinstalled it and now it works correctly.  My issue wasn't quite the same as yours, it kept redirecting to the mobile website (although I do suspect some http vs. https issue), but I would give it a try.  I know the advice seems weird because the update is like a new install, but it worked for me.